# Pandas - Get max length of lists per day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Imagine you have the following data:

```
               date          items
0              2022-03-04    [6, 7]
1              2022-03-04    [4, 8]
1              2022-03-04    [4, 8]
1              2022-03-04    [4, 8]
1              2022-03-04    [4, 8]
...                   ...       ...
1082           2022-03-03         1
1082           2022-03-03         1
1082           2022-03-03         1
1083           2022-03-11         1
1083           2022-03-11         1
```

I'd like to reach a state where I have the max length of `items` per day

```
                date         len
0               2022-03-04     2
2               2022-03-05     3
...                    ...   ...
1083            2022-03-11     1
```

etc. I dont care for duplicates, I just want the top list sizes by day in the end.

I've tried the following:

```
df["len"] = max(df.items, key=len)
```

but this seems to compute not per row, but rather on the column? as I get the following issue:

```
*** ValueError: Length of values (3) does not match length of index (4002)
```

Appreciate any assistance you can give

Comment: How are processing values if not in list?

Comment: Ideally a len of "1" or 1 should be 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) with aggregate `max`, if values are not in lists get misisng values in `df.items.str.len()`:

```
df = df.items.str.len().groupby(df['date']).max().reset_index(name='len')
```

If there is integers and need count like lenghts replace missing values by `fillna`:

```
df = (df.items.str.len().fillna(df['items'])
              .groupby(df['date'])
              .max()
              .reset_index(name='len'))
```

EDIT: If need row with maximal length of items:

```
print (df)
         date        items
0  2022-03-04        [6,7]
1  2022-03-04          [4]
1  2022-03-05  [4,8,4,4,7]
1  2022-03-05      [4,8,4]
1  2022-03-06    [4,8,5,7]


df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

df['len'] = df['items'].str.len().fillna(df['items'])
df = df.loc[df.groupby('date')['len'].idxmax()]
print (df)
         date            items  len
0  2022-03-04           [6, 7]    2
2  2022-03-05  [4, 8, 4, 4, 7]    5
4  2022-03-06     [4, 8, 5, 7]    4
```

Comment: If id like to keep the `items`column, while still doing your transformation, is that possible?

Comment: @enrm - hmmm, do you think need row per groups? Answer was edited.

Comment: i will open a new question

Comment: @enrm - added solution to my answer